# npm ERR! Failed when make ionic serve command (ask for checking version of node.js and npm installed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, ionic-framework, docker-compose

I am trying to create a docker environement (that I wish to use with git and my team) with ionic framework 2.

I have a project directory named **ionic-boilerplate**. In this directory I have an ionic app without the node_modules folder. When I do the **docker-compose up --build** command, in my docker I install all depdancies I need.

This is my **ionic-boilerplate/**`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:6.9.4

RUN npm install -g cordova@4.2.0 ionic@2.2.1

ENV DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP=/web-app

RUN mkdir -p $DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP

ADD . $DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP

RUN cd $DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP

WORKDIR $DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8100 35729

CMD ionic serve --all
```

This my **ionic-boilerplate/**`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ionic:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8100:8100"
     - "35729:35729"
    volumes:
     - .:/web-app
     - ./node_modules:/web-app/node_modules
```

When I launch the command `docker-compose up --build` or `docker-compose run ionic` I have this error:

```
Attaching to test_ionic_1
ionic_1  | npm info it worked if it ends with ok
ionic_1  | npm info using npm@3.10.10
ionic_1  | npm info using node@v6.9.4
ionic_1  | npm info lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~preionic:serve: ionic-hello-world@
ionic_1  | npm info lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~ionic:serve: ionic-hello-world@
ionic_1  | 
ionic_1  | > ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve /web-app
ionic_1  | > ionic-app-scripts serve "--all" "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
ionic_1  | 
ionic_1  | sh: 1: ionic-app-scripts: not found
ionic_1  | 
ionic_1  | npm info lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~ionic:serve: Failed to exec ionic:serve script
ionic_1  | npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
ionic_1  | npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:serve" "--" "--all" "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
ionic_1  | npm ERR! node v6.9.4
ionic_1  | npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
ionic_1  | npm ERR! file sh
ionic_1  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
ionic_1  | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
ionic_1  | npm ERR! syscall spawn
ionic_1  | npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--all" "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"`
ionic_1  | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
ionic_1  | npm ERR! 
ionic_1  | npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts serve "--all" "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"'.
ionic_1  | npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
ionic_1  | npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
ionic_1  | npm ERR! not with npm itself.
ionic_1  | npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
ionic_1  | npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts serve "--all" "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
ionic_1  | npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
ionic_1  | npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
ionic_1  | npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
ionic_1  | npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
ionic_1  | npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
ionic_1  | 
ionic_1  | npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
ionic_1  | npm ERR!     /web-app/npm-debug.log
ionic_1  | There was an error serving your Ionic application: There was an error with the spawned command: serve
test_ionic_1 exited with code 0
```

The error occured on the `Dockerfile` *instruction* `CMD ionic serve`.

This same method in local without docker, i-e make the command `npm install` then `ionic serve` works well ! Where am I wrong with the docker method ?

Comment: `RUN cd ...` and `WORKDIR` are redundant, or more correctly, that `RUN` does absolutely nothing, and should be removed. Keep only `WORKDIR`.

Comment: @DanLowe thank you, indeed I forgot to remove this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your volume mounts are overriding the image contents

Your image was built like this:

```
ENV DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP=/web-app
WORKDIR $DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP
RUN npm install
```

But at runtime, docker-compose does this:

```
volumes:
 - .:/web-app
 - ./node_modules:/web-app/node_modules
```

Because you are mounting an external path at `/web-app`, that overrides everything built into the image at that path. This can be useful during development, but there is a trade-off: you are expected to externally provide whatever is necessary at the path, because the image itself no longer can.

Using these mounts effectively reverses these steps from Dockerfile:

```
ADD . $DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP
RUN npm install
```

### Option 1: Fix it externally

One option is to run `npm install` outside the container. If you populate the external `node_modules/` with the modules needed, then the code will be happy, and should run.

### Option 2: Remove the mounts

Another option is to remove the volume mounts from docker-compose.yml, and use the code already built into the image.

This should fix the problem, at the cost of having only what is already in the image, and not being able to rapidly update it. In this scenario, every time you change the code you must rebuild the image.

### Option 3: Use an entrypoint script to do prep work

You can also use an entypoint script that does the `npm install` on container start.

**Dockerfile:**

```
ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
npm install
exec "$@"
```

This will run `npm install` on start, and then execute the `CMD` from your Dockerfile.

### Which option to pick

This is matter of picking trade-offs. The way you have things now is a common pattern during development. Because the code is mounted into the container, you can iterate rapidly. You change the code, possibly have to do a quick container restart, and the new code is running. There is no rebuild required.

But the flip side of that is, everything your app needs must be provided externally.

During development, IMO, that is a useful trade-off because you gain speed. When it comes time to deploy the application, you normally would stop using these mounts and rely on what is in the image. That way things are more predictable, and there are fewer dependencies / things that could go wrong.

The entrypoint script is the best of both worlds, because you can keep the mounts, but still update your dependencies. It does cost a little time during startup, though.

Comment: I understand that docker mount the ./node_modules on build, and there is no dependancies in it. The purpose here is to not run npm install outside the container. Have you a suggestion to make the npm install command inside the container and then share the node_modules folder with all dependancies ? Thank you for you answer by the way.

Comment: @french_dev If you want to use the modules built into the container instead of relying on external resources, then remove the two mounts. I've updated my answer with a longer explanation.

Comment: @french_dev .. and just added another update using an entrypoint script, which is something I use a lot.

Comment: your suggestion by adding an entrypoint is better than I expect, I follow your instruction, and it works like a charm ! Thank you.

Comment: @french_dev just to be clear, using the entrypoint, you no longer need `command:` in docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find another way. I remove the RUN instruction in DockerFile, then rewrite my docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - DEBUG='true'
    ports:
     - 8100:8100
     - 35729:35729
    volumes:
     - .:/web-app
     - ./node_modules:/web-app/node_modules
    command: sh -c 'npm install; ionic serve --all'
```

It works like I expect. i-e install npm package dependancies and run ionic serve command.

Don't hesitate to ask me if it's not a good practice.